# How to distinguish an unfriend versus a deactivated profile with the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting a list of a user's friends using the Facebook Android SDK, and sync'ing it with my own app's friend list.

If person A unfriends person B, I detect that and remove the relationship in my own application.

But how do I know that person A actually unfriended person B? What if he has just deactivated his profile? Is there a way I can tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would call graph.facebook.com/IdOfFriendB.  If the user unfriended them, it would either return basic info about them, or it would return simply "false" (this occurs when a user disables the whole facebook platform under app settings).  If they deactivated their profile, it would return an error message to the effect of "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist".